# Need to pick up the time and specific values (like "fcd<>", values from a specific column)

Tags: python, python-3.7

Have a large raw text file with time and other parameters. Need to take the time, fcd0, fcd2 and int values in 5th column.

sample content from the file

```
00:00:00


00:00:10    ciss0    23   1.16    76     5    71   0.03   1.13     1      0     28
             fcd0    36  11.56   953   845   108   6.58   4.98     1      0      0
            ciss4    23   1.16    76     4    72   0.03   1.13     1      0     27
             fcd2    36  11.54   953   844   109   6.58   4.96     1      0      0
00:01:00


00:01:11    ciss0    13   0.31    37     0    37   0.00   0.31     1      0     31
             fcd0     0   0.06    17     0    16   0.00   0.06     1      0      0
            ciss4    13   0.29    37     1    36   0.00   0.29     1      0     31
             fcd2     0   0.05    17     0    17   0.00   0.05     1      0      0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The important part is capturing the time for all of it's line items.

```
output = []
with open('file.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        values = re.split(r'\s+', line.strip(' \n'))
        if len(values) > 1:
            if ':' in values[0]:
                time = values[0] # capture time for period till next time comes
                if values[1] in ('fcd0', 'fcd2'):
                    output.append([time, values[1], int(values[6])])
            else:
                if values[0] in ('fcd0', 'fcd2'):
                    output.append([time, values[0], int(values[5])])
```

Output:

```
[['00:00:10', 'fcd0', 108],
['00:00:10', 'fcd2', 109],
['00:01:11', 'fcd0', 16],
['00:01:11', 'fcd2', 17]]
```